# Teechart HTML5, line color and thickness

Tags: javascript, html, teechart

How do you change the line color and thickness of a series in Teechart HTML5.

I have been looking through the examples, but i can't find anything describing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a Line series:

- To modify the line thickness, change the series `format.stroke.size` property. Ie:

  ```
  Chart1.series.items[0].format.stroke.size=2;
  ```
- To modify the series color, change the series `format.stroke.fill` property. Ie:

  ```
  Chart1.series.items[0].format.stroke.fill="red";
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but how do i change the color?